# Selenium 4, Microsoft Edge(chromium) on Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am currently trying to get my automated tests working on chromium edge on ubuntu.

My current setup is this:
**The setup is the following:**

- The browser is in a docker container with Ubuntu running
- The hub is on the official Selenium 4 docker container
- The tests or on a separate docker container running .Net Core 2.2

The RemoteWebDriver registration is the following

```cs
.....
var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
                    edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
                    edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", DownloadFolderPath);
                    edgeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
                    edgeOptions.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors"); // ignore ssl errors
                    edgeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // ignore shm usage
                    edgeOptions.AddArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests"); // ignore url cert request fetch
                    edgeOptions.AddArguments("--force-devtools-available=1"); // ignore url cert request fetch
                    edgeOptions.AddArguments($"--lang={_language}"); //set browser language from the system properties. 
                    GetEdgeDriver(builder, edgeOptions);
.......

private void GetEdgeRemoteDriver(ContainerBuilder builder, EdgeOptions options)
{
  builder
      .Register(_ => new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(RemoteEndPoint), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
      .As<IWebDriver>()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
      .OnActivated(x => x.Instance.FileDetector = new LocalFileDetector());
}
```

And we get this on the Node:

```
root@docker-desktop:/# java -jar standalone.jar node --allow-cors --publish-events tcp://192.168.50.16:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://192.168.50.16:4443 --config nodeConfig.json --allow-cors
02:24:11.283 INFO [LoggingOptions.getTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
02:24:11.285 INFO [LoggingOptions.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
02:24:11.323 INFO [EventBusOptions.createBus] - Creating event bus: org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.ZeroMqEventBus
02:24:11.374 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://192.168.50.16:4442 and tcp://192.168.50.16:4443
02:24:11.427 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
02:24:11.454 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$2] - Bus started
02:24:11.776 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Reporting self as: http://192.168.65.3:5555
02:24:11.860 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Edge for {"browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"} 2 times
02:24:12.094 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.0.0-alpha-6 (revision 5f43a29cfc): http://192.168.65.3:5555
02:24:12.100 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Starting registration process for node id e5e8efd9-e217-4967-8cfe-e312e7565523
02:24:12.398 INFO [NodeServer.lambda$execute$0] - Node has been added
Starting MSEdgeDriver 88.0.692.0 (dcff1d910f6557f2cce9c685f757a5891423af0c) on port 21256
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
Starting MSEdgeDriver 88.0.692.0 (dcff1d910f6557f2cce9c685f757a5891423af0c) on port 11003
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
Starting MSEdgeDriver 88.0.692.0 (dcff1d910f6557f2cce9c685f757a5891423af0c) on port 24739
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
Starting MSEdgeDriver 88.0.692.0 (dcff1d910f6557f2cce9c685f757a5891423af0c) on port 16505
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
```

And this on the hub side:

```
02:24:32.050 WARN [SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute] - Unable to execute request: Unable to create session for <CreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeChromium: true, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-re..., --lang=ja], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\Users\nicolae.farcas\Des...}}}>
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session for <CreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeChromium: true, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-re..., --lang=ja], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\Users\nicolae.farcas\Des...}}}>
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$1(Slot.java:86)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$2(Slot.java:85)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:208)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.lambda$new$0(Distributor.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.execute(Distributor.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:85)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.WrapExceptions.lambda$apply$0(WrapExceptions.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
02:24:32.051 WARN [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$1] - {"traceId": "66e211f62bb44e6b57383c938386aa63","spanId": "d0836ebcedb75323","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605666272050023400,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException","exception.message": "Unable to execute request: Unable to create session for \u003cCreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeChromium: true, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-re..., --lang=ja], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\\Users\\nicolae.farcas\\Des...}}}>\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'\nSystem info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor","http.url": "\u002fsession","exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session for \u003cCreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeChromium: true, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-re..., --lang=ja], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\\Users\\nicolae.farcas\\Des...}}}>\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'\nSystem info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$1(Slot.java:86)\n\tat java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$2(Slot.java:85)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:208)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.lambda$new$0(Distributor.java:89)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:183)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.execute(Distributor.java:124)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:85)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:30)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.WrapExceptions.lambda$apply$0(WrapExceptions.java:36)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:46)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","http.method": "POST"}}
```

And the nodeConfig.json:

```json
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "version": "88.0.692.0",
      "applicationName": "Edge Node",
      "webdriver.edge.driver": "msedgedriver",
      "ms:edgeChromium": true
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 20,
  "port": -1,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://192.168.50.16:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 5,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Test output:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException
Unable to create session for <CreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeChromium: true, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-re..., --lang=ja], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\Users\nicolae.farcas\Des...}}}>
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

EDIT 1:
When trying to run selenium alpha-7 as a node, i get this:

```
root@docker-desktop:/# java -jar standalone-4.0-alpha-7.jar node --allow-cors --publish-events tcp://192.168.50.16:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://192.168.50.16:4443 --config nodeConfig.json
15:26:00.250 INFO [LogManager$RootLogger.log] - Using the system default encoding
15:26:00.253 INFO [LoggingOptions.getTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
15:26:00.253 INFO [LoggingOptions.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
15:26:00.319 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://192.168.50.16:4442 and tcp://192.168.50.16:4443
15:26:00.358 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
15:26:00.360 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$7] - Bus started
15:26:00.576 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://192.168.65.3:5555
15:26:00.581 INFO [LoggingOptions.getTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
15:26:00.583 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://192.168.50.16:4442 and tcp://192.168.50.16:4443
15:26:00.585 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
15:26:00.586 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$7] - Bus started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find class: org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNodeFactory
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.Config.getClass(Config.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.lambda$getClass$4(MemoizedConfig.java:99)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.getClass(MemoizedConfig.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.getNode(NodeOptions.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.createHandlers(NodeServer.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.asServer(NodeServer.java:176)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.execute(NodeServer.java:217)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.TemplateGridCommand.lambda$configure$2(TemplateGridCommand.java:98)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.launch(Main.java:154)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.go(Main.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.main(Main.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.Config.getClass(Config.java:69)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.FileReader.<init>(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)V
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.LinuxEphemeralPortRangeDetector.getInstance(LinuxEphemeralPortRangeDetector.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.<clinit>(PortProber.java:42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:401)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverInfo.isAvailable(ChromeDriverInfo.java:57)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.discoverDrivers(NodeOptions.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.getSessionFactories(NodeOptions.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNodeFactory.create(LocalNodeFactory.java:66)
        ... 16 more
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/standalone-4.0-alpha-7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

EDIT 2:
After updating to Java 11, the error from `EDIT 1` is gone but I am still seeing issues running the tests. The grid at `/status` tells me it's up but when I try running tests I get this:

From the tests:

```cs
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException
Unauthorized access attempted to 
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

From the hub:

```
16:26:36.171 WARN [SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute] - Unable to execute request: Unauthorized access attempted to
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unauthorized access attempted to
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'
System info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.Values.get(Values.java:47)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.remote.RemoteNode.newSession(RemoteNode.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$2(Slot.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:208)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.lambda$new$0(Distributor.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.execute(Distributor.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:85)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.WrapExceptions.lambda$apply$0(WrapExceptions.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16:26:36.172 WARN [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$1] - {"traceId": "6c98780410750ac145fcc0bcdc6075f1","spanId": "1a237f64fb417958","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605716796170301100,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException","exception.message": "Unable to execute request: Unauthorized access attempted to \nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'\nSystem info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor","http.url": "\u002fsession","exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unauthorized access attempted to \nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: '117b9d61c9'\nSystem info: host: '836e92c76b1f', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:141)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.Values.get(Values.java:47)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.remote.RemoteNode.newSession(RemoteNode.java:114)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.model.Slot.lambda$onReserve$2(Slot.java:84)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:208)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.lambda$new$0(Distributor.java:89)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:183)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.Distributor.execute(Distributor.java:124)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:85)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:327)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:67)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:30)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.WrapExceptions.lambda$apply$0(WrapExceptions.java:36)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:46)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","http.method": "POST"}}
```

From the node:

```
16:26:36.070 WARN [RequiresSecretFilter.isSecretMatch] - Unexpectedly received registration secret to (POST) /se/grid/node/session
16:26:36.078 WARN [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "7bd8f4e2a6a68f396b4d73d7ce41920e","spanId": "413eadfe028cb4f3","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605716796076570700,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.status_code": 401,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.security.RequiresSecretFilter$$Lambda$356\u002f0x0000000840219040","http.url": "\u002fse\u002fgrid\u002fnode\u002fsession","http.method": "POST"}}

16:26:36.164 WARN [RequiresSecretFilter.isSecretMatch] - Unexpectedly received registration secret to (POST) /se/grid/node/session
16:26:36.165 WARN [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "c71c7cc95c85b1d892a913a8487a3bb3","spanId": "e7cad4724bde618f","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605716796164917000,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.status_code": 401,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.security.RequiresSecretFilter$$Lambda$356\u002f0x0000000840219040","http.url": "\u002fse\u002fgrid\u002fnode\u002fsession","http.method": "POST"}}

16:26:45.135 INFO [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "f9aa30acdd23b666a00fd12d1e9171de","spanId": "3a26d851115e4ed8","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605716805135500700,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.status_code": 200,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute","http.url": "\u002fstatus","http.method": "GET"}}

16:26:56.789 INFO [LoggingOptions$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "0be52be996fecb3cfeb4981cc69e4719","spanId": "034962023cad771b","spanKind": "INTERNAL","eventTime": 1605716816788987800,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.status_code": 200,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute","http.url": "\u002fstatus","http.method": "GET"}}
```

Comment: Just tried it on Ubuntu (Without docker )machine with 4.0.0-alpha-7 ,MSEdgeDriver 88.0.692.0 & Edge for linux with grid (hub+node) setup. Its working fine  . Check the node version you are using in logs its showing '[NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.0.0-alpha-6 (revision 5f43a29cfc)' & Hub is alpha-7 . Use same version for node & hub then give try one more time.

Comment: .Net5 - Also in .Net binding of selenium (alpha7) looks like there is bug . It gives exception Content-Type header missing if RemoteWebdriver is used. In Java binding alpha 7 its fixed and working fine

Comment: I am not sure.. may be this matters. You have `download.default_directory` preference set in windows style like `C:\\Users\\..` however you are running your browser in Ubuntu.

Comment: @RahulL I tried alpha-7 but i get the error from the Edit

Comment: AFter updating to java 11, this error is not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```json
    "webdriver.edge.driver": "msedgedriver",
```

from `capabilities`, and add:

```sh
-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=/path/to/msedgedriver
```

to your node call. For example:

```
java -jar /path/to/selenium-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=/path/to/msedgedriver -role node -nodeConfig /path/to/node-config.json
```

Ah, and your `browserName` **must** be `MicrosoftEdge` (you have it, but mentioning it for others reading this).

This worked for me for Selenium 3.